# HTML + TypeScript : change value of field based on other field

Tags: html, typescript

I just started working with HTML and TypeScript and I'm stuck trying to set value of field depending on the value selected for another field in my HTML form.

HTML

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-control-label" jhiTranslate="country.status" for="field_status">Status</label>
                    <select class="form-control" name="status" formControlName="status" id="field_status">
                        <option value="ACCEPTED">{{ 'CountryStatus.ACCEPTED' | translate }}</option>
                        <option value="CHECK_ONGOING">{{ 'CountryStatus.CHECK_ONGOING' | translate }}</option>
                        <option value="CHANGE_REQUESTED">{{ 'CountryStatus.CHANGE_REQUESTED' | translate }}</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

<div class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-control-label" jhiTranslate="country.approvalDate" for="field_approvalDate">Approval Date</label>
                    <div class="d-flex">
                        <input id="field_approvalDate" type="datetime-local" class="form-control" name="approvalDate" formControlName="approvalDate" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm" />
                    </div>
                </div>
```

WHat I want to achieve is following :

When I select status (Accepted), I want to have approval date field automatically set to now.
In case I select another status rather than Accepted, the approval date is cleared.

[image]

I assume I have to write a sort of function in my component.ts class but not sure.

Can you please give me some pointers / leads ? Thank you!

Comment: Add change handler to select list

Comment: Thanks @vaibhav for your answer. This change handler should be added at html or TypeScript level ?